# How can I handle the presigned URL expire before finish downloading?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS s3 presigned URL for download and upload files to S3 bucket. The presigned URL has an expire date. If the expire is 15 minutes and clients is downloading a big file from S3 before it expires, what happen if the download takes more than 15 minutes?

Will it abort the download/uploading? I can't find any description in AWS doc.

Comment: Such a great question. Thankfully, there is no need to handle it. But great to know. You're thinking ahead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will it abort the download/uploading?

It **will not be aborted**. The credentials are only needed to initiate the download process. Once it starts it will continue until finished, whether or not the link expired.